Why does the or operator in fish seem to not work
function shapeshift
   argparse 'h/help' -- $argv
   if not set -q argv[1] $argv or if set -q _flag_help 
      echo "Shapeshift lets you change into another root system."
      echo "It is a simple tool that mounts, and chroots a partition of your choice."
      echo ""
      echo "Use it in the following way:"
      set_color green; echo "shapeshift nvme0n1p4"; set_color normal
      echo ""
      echo "Here is a list of the available partitions:"
      echo ""
      sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINTS,TYPE | awk '$4 == "part"'
   end
end

I cant seem to get both, calling with an argument and calling with --help, seem to get working at the same time.
I tried several different versions of this code, and always seems to break the code, once I chain both events together by an or. No matter which one I call first, or if I use a separate if statement in front of the second command or not. It always seems to fail.

Is the syntax really or if? Shouldn't it be just or?

See Fish syntax: Combiners: and or. And don't make up your own syntax, and when you get a syntax error say so. Thirty seconds in Google to find this.

I tried this before. It does cause the code to break as well. But I figured it out; It works with semicolon.

As you haven't provided any error messages, or this actual solution, it is impossible to tell what you're talking about, but if you're claiming that or if is correct, you're wrong.

It didnt work with or neither. :)

In fish shell, "or" is specially recognized when used as a command, but only in "command position;" otherwise it's just a plain old string.
The second issue is that one should not write if X; or if Y because this tests the result of a nested if statement. Instead, write if X; or Y
For example, don't do this:
if not set -q argv[1] or if set -q _flag_help

This is a single invocation of set which passes "or", "if", etc as arguments, which is not intended. Instead, make a new command with a semicolon, and no nested "if":
if not set -q argv[1]; or set -q _flag_help

Or use a newline:
if not set -q argv[1]
or set -q _flag_help
...
end

Alternatively you may prefer the || syntax, which itself creates a new command:
if not set -q argv[1] || set -q _flag_help
...

Note set -q argv[1] is sufficient to test that there is at least one argument. Do not also pass $argv; that would check if any of the arguments is the name of a variable.
So give this a try:
function shapeshift
   argparse 'h/help' -- $argv
   if not set -q argv[1] || set -q _flag_help 
      echo "Shapeshift lets you change into another root system."
      echo "It is a simple tool that mounts, and chroots a partition of your choice."
      echo ""
      echo "Use it in the following way:"
      set_color green; echo "shapeshift nvme0n1p4"; set_color normal
      echo ""
      echo "Here is a list of the available partitions:"
      echo ""
      sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINTS,TYPE | awk '$4 == "part"'
   end
end


I dont know why, but this seems to work:
function shapeshift
   argparse 'h/help' -- $argv
   # Print the available partitions if no one given
   if not parameter_is_provided $argv; if set -q _flag_help
      echo "Shapeshift lets you change into another root system."
      echo "It is a simple tool that mounts, and chroots a partition of your choice."
      echo ""
      echo "Use it in the following way:"
      set_color green; echo "shapeshift nvme0n1p4"; set_color normal
      echo ""
      echo "Here is a list of the available partitions:"
      echo ""
      sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,MOUNTPOINTS,TYPE | awk '$4 == "part"'
      return 0
   end
end  


It works because it's a nested IF, but it implements and, not or.

I dont see an and, the only occurrence of it is as part of a string.
I did it with a ; now. But or should do it, or not?
